# Should I use a lens hood for my EF-S 24mm f/2.8 STM?

Tags: canon, lens-hood

I have a Canon EOS Rebel T7, with a EF-S 24mm f/2.8 STM. I plan to use this lens for mainly outdoor use.

I was wondering if I should use a lens hood with this lens. If I should, do you recommend a petal lens or a cylindrical lens hood?

Comment: You should use the lens hood designed for the canon 24mm lens you have whenever you want to stop a light source ( *the sun* ) from creating lens flare on your  your photos. You would not need it if the sun was behind you or far enough off to the side, but the 24 has a wide angle of view.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you recommend a petal lens or a cylindrical lens hood?

Neither. Use the unconventional design that Canon created for the EF-S 24mm f/2.8 STM.

Since a 24mm on a 1.6X APS-C crop body has the same field of view as a 40mm lens on FF, it's the same hood that fits the other Canon pancake lens, the EF 40mm f/2.8 STM.

The [ES-52](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/871017-REG/Canon_ES_52_Lens_Hood.html) lens hood:

[image]

For how this type of design works, please see: [How does lens-hoods for pancake lenses work? (Canon EF 40mm with ES-52)](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46986/15871)

If you want a cheap knock-off, [they're out there](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07V5NRPRF) too. They claim to be made of aluminum alloy, just like the Canon.

Comment: Is ES-52 really a lens hodd???? I use the same 50 mm. 1.8 II lens hood wich is cylindrical. It fits perfect on 24mm. with no vigneting. The model number is ES-62.

Comment: Yes. It is a [different type of lens hood](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46987/15871) made to complement the compactness of the EF-S 24mm f/2.8 STM lens. The ES-62 is much bulkier than the EF-S 24mm or the ES-52.